# mat-form-field is displayed with the error cue even though it's pristine and untouched when declared in ng-template in a different component

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-template

Default angular/ angular material behavior is not to overwhelm the user with error cues when a control is pristine and untouched (i.e. a control is shown for the first time and is invalid but the user hasn't interacted with it yet). For some reason, when a `mat-form-field` is declared as an `ng-template` and used via `ng-container`/`ngTemplateOutlet`, it's highlighted even though it has `ng-untouched` and `ng-pristine`. This is only reproducible when ng-template is declared in a different component.

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-material-starter-yvqsck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
[image]

I'm using `mat-stepper` with two steps:

*Step 1* Has `TemplateStepComponent` component that declares `ng-template` with `mat-form-field`. this template is saved in `TemplateStepComponent.template` static field.

*Step 2* has three `mat-form-field` which are bound to the same `item: FormControl` with `Validators.required`.

1. Is rendered using `ngTemplateOutlet` and using a TemplateRef declared in the previous step - `TemplateStepComponent.template`. Expected: no error, Actual: highlighted even though it's untouched and pristine
2. Is similar to the first one but the `ng-template` and `ng-container`/`ngTemplateOutlet` are inlined. Behaves as expected.
3. The third one is a regular `mat-form-field` and behaves and is expected.

Not really sure why #1 doesn't work as expected even though it's pristine and untouched. It definitely has to do with the fact that the template is declared outside of the current component but I don't understand why it matters.

I found that usage of `<form>` with `<button type=submit>` can trigger this behavior ([Angular Material form control highlighted in red even though pristine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956205/angular-material-form-control-highlighted-in-red-even-though-pristine)) but I don't use forms nor the fix helps in my case.

Comment: It's the expected behavior: when you have a mat-form-field inside a step, if you goes to another step and return is "marked as red". You can goes from step 1 to step 2 and again to step 1 and again to step 2 and you can see all the form-field in red. As you have declared the `<app-template-step>` in the step 1, when goes to step 2 you see it "red bordered". (you can put the component in step 2 if you want the same behavior the others)

Comment: @Eliseo, the issue I'm trying to figure is why the first mat-form-field red when we go 1->2, not 1->2->1->2. Thanks for checking this issue.

Comment: you declare the template in the first step, not in the second. IF you move the `<app-template-step>` to the second step, works as usual.

Comment: @Eliseo, oh I see what you meant - `mat-stepper` "remembers" the `ng-template` defined in the first step, and after switching to step 2, `mat-stepper` marks the ng-container with the same template since it was shown in step 1. I did a slightly different and confirmed it. Now, I know what's the reason behind the error state but I struggling to understand why mat-stepper cares about `ng-template`? if it were a regular control, it would make sense. But, why does it care about `ng-template` when even Angular doesn't render it. Can you explain it? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Eliseo, pointed out mat-stepper is the culprit: when we navigate away from the step where template is defined, mat-stepper marks the `mat-form-field` as invalid ignoring bound FormControl.
I created a better example to point this out:
[image]
Source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-material-starter-yvqsck?file=README.md

It's not exactly clear to me how `mat-stepper` marks the `mat-form-field` as invalid inside of the template